# rolling regression by group in the data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, regression, rolling-computation

I wondered whether the frollapply can be leveraged to run a regression in data.table environment? I can perform this task using rollRegres and tidy as follows

```
   DT <- DT %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   do(.,mutate(.,Beta = roll_regres(Y ~ X,.,252)$coef[,2]))
```

The above code tries to return the slope of regression on a rolling window using 252 days. I would appreciate any feedback on this and whether frollapply solution, if relevant, is faster than the above code.

Comment: `frollapply` is relatively slow, so it won't help much. As of now it accept single vector anyway, so cannot deal with regression. I think your current approach is optimal. Feel free to self answer your question. Also see https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4075